# Kotlin all-open compiler plugin doesn't work

Tags: kotlin

I use Realm and it requires `open` keyword to it's model classes.

Following https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/12/kotlin-1-0-6-is-here/,
I tried to use all-open compiler plugin to remove the `open` keyword from Realm model classes.

First, I added all-open compiler plugin and set the package name of annotation

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"

allOpen {
  annotation("com.mycompany.myapp.annotation")
}
```

Second, I generated annotation

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.annotation
annotation class AllOpenAnnotation
```

Finally, I added the annotation to Realm model class

```
@AllOpenAnnotation
class Model {
  var id: Int = -1,
  var title: String = "",
  var desc: String? = null
}: RealmObject()
```

But the `error: cannot inherit from final Model` error occurs.

Is there something that I did wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the name of the annotation to the path in your config file:

```
allOpen {
    annotation("com.mycompany.myapp.annotation.AllOpenAnnotation")
}
```